# What's the word for a loop that reverts direction after completing its cycle?

Tags: word-choice

If I take a set of elements that can be put in an order, for example the numbers 1,2,3,4 what is it called when I visit the elements from the beginning to the end, and invert direction whenever hitting either the end or the beginning? After going from 3 to 4, the next number would be 3 again. This is distinct from a loop where direction is not inverted and the next number after 4 would be 1. At least that's how I see it. The context is programming.

Comment: This may not be an exact fit for programming, but there's the concept of **serpentine**, as in a _serpentine draft_, which [one website](http://football.about.com/od/fantasyfootball/a/fantasyglossary.htm) defines as: "A style of draft where the order of selection is reversed each round. For example, the team that drafts last in the first round drafts first in the second round."

Comment: I cannot think of an actual term for this, but perhaps something like ‘phone dial’ could work (for those who still remember phones with actual dials)?

Comment: There's [Oscillating Universe](http://www.universetoday.com/38195/oscillating-universe-theory/) *a cosmological model that combines both the Big Bang and the Big Crunch as part of a cyclical event.* So perhaps you could get away with *oscillating loop*, but you'd probably have to define the term on first use. As Colin says, there's probably not a generally-known term.

Comment: As in *alternating current*: alternating scanning, alternating looping, alternating traversal.

Comment: [Triangle wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a generally known word. I would call it *reciprocating*, or *sweeping in alternate directions*, but I would not expect people to understand without explanation.

Comment: Or perhaps even "alternating"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: maybe, but _alternating_ could have other meanings.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen numbers like 1234321, the numbers of the sequence described concatenated together, called [*palindromic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number). If the sequence ends and if that end is the first element, the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) entry suggests you can use the word *palindrome* to refer to it:

> A palindrome is a word, phrase, number, or **other sequence of symbols or elements**, whose meaning may be interpreted the same way in either forward or reverse direction.

Note that this is **not** always the same as saying *sequence of the palindrome 1234321*; such a loop would have two 1's together.

In a programming context, this [jit.qt.movie documentation](http://www.cycling74.com/docs/max5/refpages/jit-ref/jit.qt.movie.html) (for editing/playing video) has a loop attribute with a palindrome mode, described as:

> palindrome looping (start to end to start to ....)

Personally, if I didn't know beforehand where the loop would end, I would use J.R.'s suggestion of *serpentine* instead.